# Understanding where all the equations from a covariant derivative of a tensor come from

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, covariance

Suppose I have a situation where i know that $\nabla_i T^{ik}=0$ where $ T^{ik}$ is a tensor of rank 2, which is diagonal, such as the perfect fluid energy-momentum tensor.
We are dealing in a coordinate system $X_i = {{t,r,\theta,\phi}} $

Apparently  $\nabla_i T^{ik}=0$ is supposed to represent four equations however I fail to see where they come from.
I know that  $\nabla_i T^{ik}=  ∂iT^{ij} +Γ^{i}_{ik}T^{kj} +Γ^j_{ik}T^{ik}$ but am unable to see how one would get the equations from this sort of equation.

I assume I can set $k$ to 0,1,2,3 and that will represent each equation but unsure what to do past that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume I can set k to 0,1,2,3 and that will represent each equation but unsure what to do past that point.

But that's all there is to it.  If e.g. you set $k=0$, you get the equation

$$\nabla_i T^{i0} = \frac{\partial T^{i0}}{\partial x^i} + \Gamma^i_{ \ \ i\alpha} T^{\alpha 0} + \Gamma^0_{i \alpha}T^{i\alpha}$$
If $T^{ij}$ is diagonal, then this would reduce to

$$ \frac{\partial T^{00}}{\partial x^0} + \Gamma^i_{\ \ i0}T^{00} + \Gamma^0_{\ \ 00}T^{00} + \Gamma^0_{\ \ 11}T^{11} + \Gamma^0_{\ \ 22}T^{22} + \Gamma^0_{\ \ 33} T^{33} = 0$$

Setting $k$ equal to the other three possible values gives you three more equations.

Comment: @DJA The covariant divergence is a bit more complicated than that - see the correction I just made.  But the idea is the same - there are four possible values of $k$, which means four different equations.

Comment: @DJA I don't know what you mean by that.  In my last equation, all of those entries of $T$ are on the main diagonal, and are therefore nonzero.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment didn't actually make sense when I read it back. The equation $\Gamma^i_{\ \ i0}T^{00}  $ is a summation over the i  I assume.

Comment: @DJA Yes, so there are four terms there - $\Gamma^i_{i0}T^{00}=(\Gamma^0_{00}+\Gamma^1_{10}+\Gamma^2_{20}+\Gamma^3_{30})T^{00}$.

Comment: Thank you! You are always such a great help!!!

Comment: @DJA I'm glad I could be of assistance!